# Explaining Gaussian Processes

Tags: normal-distribution, stochastic-processes

I am finding it hard to understand Gaussian Processes. Can someone please explain it here in an accessible way? I do understand what Gaussian distribution is but couldn't understand Gaussian Processes. Or if you could provide some great resources to quickly learn about it.

Answer (score 10):

Well, the details of the answer will depend on how much you know about
random processes in general.  If you know that a random process is a
collection of random variables, then a Gaussian process is one in which
*all* the random variables are Gaussian (a.k.a. normal) random variables;
more strongly, they are *jointly Gaussian* random variables.  In an answer
on dsp.SE, [I wrote in part](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/488/235)

> Finally, suppose that a stochastic process is **assumed** to be a *Gaussian* process ("proving" this with any reasonable degree of confidence is not a trivial task).
>   This means that for each $t$, $X(t)$ is a Gaussian random variable and for all positive integers $n \geq 2$ and choices of $n$ time instants $t_1$, $t_2$, $\ldots, t_n$, the $N$
>   random variables $X(t_1)$, $X(t_2)$, $\ldots, X(t_n)$ are *jointly Gaussian* random
>   variables.  Now a joint Gaussian density function is *completely* determined by the means, variances, and covariances of the random variables, and in this case, knowing the mean function $\mu_X(t) = E[X(t)]$ (it need not be a constant as is required for wide-sense-stationarity) and the autocorrelation function $R_X(t_1, t_2) = E[X(t_1)X(t_2)]$ for all $t_1, t_2$ (it need not depend only on $t_1-t_2$ as is required for wide-sense-stationarity) is sufficient to determine the statistics of the process completely.

If none of this makes sense to you, try reading the full answer on dsp.SE.

Answer (score 5):

This short tutorial by Eden : [Gaussian Processes for Regression: A Quick Introduction](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~mebden/reports/GPtutorial.pdf), is the simplest and most direct material I can think of for getting out quickly somewhat up to speed with GPs, it should take you less that an hour or two I think. Somewhat longer is the excellent tutorial paper by Williams :  [Prediction with Gaussian processes: From linear regression to linear prediction and beyond](http://www.dai.ed.ac.uk/homes/ckiw/postscript/NCRG_97_012.ps.gz). Finally the "ultimate" general resource is [the Gaussian Process Web site](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/); it has tutorials, papers categorized by field of applications, software implementations, etc.

And if you are into lectures, check the [2006 round of lectures in Bletchley Park](http://videolectures.net/gpip06_bletchley_park/). Lots of big names (eg. MacKey, Williams, Rasmussen, etc.) and a variety of applications span. (In general the [Videolectures web site](http://videolectures.net/) has tones of material on ML stuff.)

(and clearly +1 to Dilip; that's a great post on the DSP-SE web site!)

Answer (score 1):

I am working on Gaussian processes in my Ph.D. and yes, it was very confusing in beginning. I would strongly recommend [this YouTube video lecture](https://youtu.be/92-98SYOdlY) as the best resource to understand Gaussian processes from a regression perspective.